# How do you change the default window size of windows-curses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

When I initialize a window in curses with something like

```
curses.initscr()
stdscr = curses.newwin(0,0,0,0)
```

it always seems to have a default resolution of 120x30 characters that you can't change the resolution beyond.
**How do you create a window with a resolution beyond this, or change the current window to a higher resolution?** I'm trying to make a fullscreen (bordered) window, but it doesn't seem to want to go past the standard 120x30 size. Even when the terminal itself is maximized, it simply doesn't show or update anything beyond the edges of the original 120x30 space it started in.

Comment: I don't think Curses has the power to set the terminal size. I believe it works the other way around - the application has to fit the terminal's current setup and adapt to whatever dimensions it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curses ***uses*** the terminal's screensize; it doesn't ***set*** the terminal's screensize.